# Javascript string interpolation ways to use

Tags: javascript

I came across this example of a developer where he used string interpolation.

The way he used it was as follow :

```
console.log(`Hello, $userName`);
```

I didn't see anything wrong with that until later in his example. He did string interpolation again but differently this time. This time he used brackets. like this:

```
console.log(`The user asked ${question}`);
```

What's the difference ? Does it matter which way I use? or is it simply a mistake from the developer.

Comment: The last line is the answer you are looking for: *it is simply a mistake from the developer.*

Comment: The first example just looks like a syntax error to me

Comment: Important is, that the latter one is correct.

Comment: The first snippet will not be treated as string interpolation

Comment: ha everybody jumps on it so quick

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easiest way is to try

As you can see the first does not do anything

```js
var $userName = "Mike", userName = "Michael", question = "What's up?"

console.log(`Hello, $userName`); // not a valid JS string interpolation

console.log(`The user asked ${question}`); // This one works

// Perhaps he meant

console.log(`Hello`, $userName); 

// or more likely

console.log(`Hello, ${userName}`);
```